Does spyOn(console, 'log') check all the output? Did I find a bug?
In my console, I see this:
  console.log
    27 (>$-1 not safe, so NOT) buying 0.6573442493668066 XBTUSD at 62777 with leverage none to close at 63718.7 as 1747062777

My test code says:
await bot.report();
expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    expect.stringMatching(/buying 0.6573442493668066 XBTUSD at 62777/));

Jest test output says:
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: StringMatching /buying 0.6573442493668066 XBTUSD at 62777/
Received
       1: ...

I run the test using npm test which refers to the line in my package.json that says:
"scripts": {
  "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest --verbose",

My best theory about why this happens is that while Jest is actually spying on console output, there is something about Node.js and/or Jest that prevents it from seeing this line.  In the "Jest output" section above I only listed "1: ..." but there are three calls listed and they do reflect previous console.log output. I didn't want to have to count how many outputs appear before what I'm looking for, but maybe toHaveBeenCalledWith only watches the first few logs. I'll keep trying to figure this out, but if someone knows why it isn't seeing the output that is plain to me reading the console output, please let me know!
After creating a test case to demonstrate the problem, I believe that spying on console log might work correctly if it is intended to recognize only those calls in which all arguments passed to console.log are are specified.  If there is a way to have it check each argument passed to the spy for a matching string, that would be helpful. Here is my test case:
File logAlot.js is:
export function logAlot() {
  function log1000() {
        console.log('haystack',"DhG44n", 'haystack');
  }
return {log1000};
}

My spy.test.mjs is:
import {expect, describe, test, jest} from '@jest/globals';
import { logAlot } from '../logAlot.js';

test("find match", async () => {
    const consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(console, "log");
    const LA = logAlot();
    LA.log1000();
    expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.stringMatching('DhG44n'));
} );

The output shows:
 FAIL  test/spy.test.mjs (5.635 s)
✕ find match (99 ms)

● find match

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: StringMatching /DhG44n/
Received: "haystack", "DhG44n", "haystack"

Number of calls: 1

  6 |     const LA = logAlot();
  7 |     LA.log1000();
> 8 |     expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.stringMatching('DhG44n'));
    |                        ^
  9 | } );

  at Object.<anonymous> (test/spy.test.mjs:8:24)


That is how mock assertions work - the arguments are checked positionally. If you want to say "has ever been called with this value in any position", you'd need to access the mock info directly, look at the call list. Or just expect.any() in the other positions if you know only the second argument.

No, this is not a bug. In toHaveBeenCalledWith, the arguments are checked positionally, as explained in the first comment.
If you run into this problem and would like to avoid it for console.log specifically, a relatively simple fix is to use template strings in Javascript instead of passing arguments that console.log concatenates with a space. A template string uses backticks (`) to delineate the string, and will execute code which is placed between ${ and } inside the string.  The result is a single string, parts of which are the result of executing the code in the ${} parts, and so console.log will get called with a single argument. Thus, your call to any of the various Jest matchers will see the whole string as the first argument.
